# How to add and substract total duration

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php $_POST variable where it displays the total duration from a previous page. The variable is below:

```
<?php  $postduration  = $_POST['durationChosen']; ?>
```

The format of the Total Duration is like this `"00 Hrs 00 Mins 00 Secs"`

What I have is a textbox and linked with that textbox is a timepicker where the user can select their duration for each question. Again the format of the duration displayed in the timepicker
is "00 Hrs oo Mins 00 Secs".

What will happen is the user will select a duration from the timepicker and it will be displayed in a textbox (this happens at the top). The user is then able to click on the "Add" button and what this does is
that it adds the duration in a new row in a textbox. The user can change the duration within an added row if they wish.

Now what the total duration needs to do is to automatically be subtracted or added depending on what is displayed in the added rows.

I will give you an example below by text on what I mean:

```
Total Duration when page first opened: 00 Hrs 30 Mins 00 Secs


Total Duration Now: 00 Hrs 05 Mins 00 Secs


Row 1:  00 Hrs 10 mins 00 Secs
Row 2:  00 Hrs 10 mins 00 Secs
Row 3:  00 Hrs 05 mins 00 Secs
```

If you look at exampe above what it is stating is that when the page was first opened there was a total duration of 00 Hrs 30 Mins 00 Secs. But I have added 3 Rows which all contains their
duration. Altogether the 3 rows makes 25 minutes. So the Total Duration now displays 00 Hrs 05 Mins 00 Secs. This is because 30 mins minus 25 mins equals 5 mins remaining.

So does anyone know haw this can be achieved (P.S I want the total duration to display this format if Total Duration is surpasses "- 00 Hrs 00 Mins 00 Secs" (Minus is included in this format))

Below shows the code of the main textbox with timepicker which is used and then added into new rows (I want Total Duration to add or minus depending on selection in this textbox):

```
<table id="questionDuration">
<tr>
     <th colspan="2">
     Question Duration
     </th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="questiondurationpicker" name="questionDuration" readonly="readonly" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Total Duration Remaining: <strong><?php echo $postduration; ?></strong></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function() {  
    $('#questiondurationpicker').trenttimepicker({
            timeFormat:'hh mm ss',
            hourGrid: 4,
            minuteGrid: 10,
            secondGrid: 10,
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImage: "Images/clock.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true
            });

            });
```

Below is code displaying the textboxes with timepickers for each row which have been added (I want Total Duration to add or minus depending on what is displayed in these textboxes for each row)

Jquery:

```
function insertQuestion(form) {  

var $tr = $("<tr></tr>");
var $duration = $("<td class='duration'></td>")

     $('#questiondurationpicker').each( function() {

     var $this = $(this);
     var $durationText = $("<input type='text' class='questiondurationpickerRow' readonly='readonly' />").attr('name',$this.attr('name'))
                     .attr('value',$this.val())

    $duration.append($durationText);

    });

    $tr.append($duration);
    $('#qandatbl').append($tr);

$('.questiondurationpickerRow').trenttimepicker({
            timeFormat:'hh mm ss',
            hourGrid: 4,
            minuteGrid: 10,
            secondGrid: 10,
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImage: "Images/clock.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true
            });

}
```

Thank you and hopefully this makes sense. If not then please tell me and I will try and clarify it best I can.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly, all you need to do is to add names to additional textboxes created via "Add" button you mention at the beginning. Probably creating an array is the best, for example: `name="additionalDuration[]"`

Then in your PHP file you will have two $_POST variables: base duration and an array of additional durations. At this point all you need is to parse all durations and add or substract them to calculate the total duration and then format it the way you want.

If you need help with parsing the submited time and calculations, feel free to post a comment to this answer.

**Update, example of submitted parsing:**

```
// example function to convert submitted date into seconds
function time_to_seconds($str) {
    if (preg_match("#^(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)$#", trim($str), $match))
        return $match[3] + 60 * $match[2] + 3600 * $match[1];
    return 0;
}
// taking base time as a starting amount
$total_duration = time_to_seconds($_POST['baseDuration']);

// for each additional user input calculating the total duration
foreach ($_POST['additionalDuration'] as $add)
    $total_duration -= time_to_seconds($add);

// formatting the output
echo date("H \H\r\s i \m\i\n\s s \S\e\c\s", $total_duration);
```

As I saw in your post, all additional data is substracted from the base duration. That's why I'm using `-=` for each of them. Correct me if I'm wrong.
And again, feel free to ask further questions should they appear.

Comment: Hi, sorry I have been trying to code this array and parsing the submitted time and calculations and I am completly making a hash of it. I keep getting errors and I am getting no way near. Do you know how to code this, can you provide a sample when you have time because I am really struggling :)